# How to quantify consistency in an distirbution?

Tags: distributions

Consistency seems to be a great tool for understanding the properties of a probability distirbution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator

Are there any metrics to quantify the consistency of a distributions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Consistent estimators for the entire distribution?

Comment: The question makes little sense. There is no such thing as consistency of a distribution. There is no such thing as quantifying consistency. It is far from clear what your question is.

Comment: @Greenparker In fact, _consistency_ is a good name in use for measures of how far different directions (e.g. bird movements, wind directions) agree. But despite puzzlement over this question we can be confident with probability 1 that this isn't the issue at all. It's just that "no such thing as quantifying consistency" isn't correct without that qualification.

Comment: @NickCox fair point. Will be a little more careful in future when making blanket statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a consistent estimator for the entire distribution then the empirical distribution function $\hat{F}_n(s) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(x_i \leq s)$ will work.  A result called the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem states that $\sup_{s \in \mathbb{R}} |\hat{F}_n(s) - F(s)| \to 0$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$, so eventually $\hat{F}$ will be close to $F$ everywhere.